# Control flow in recursion python

Tags: python, recursion

I created the following function:

```
def test_recursion(x):
    print(x)
    while x < 10:
        test_recursion(x+1)
        test_recursion(x+2)
    print("end of function reached")

test_recursion(1)
```

What I don't understand is why after x reaches 10 and the end of function print statement is reached, it keeps printing 11 then 10 in an infinite loop.

Should the program not end after 10 is printed?

Comment: There are two recursive calls in your function. Plus you're using a while loop inside the function so the while test is always true for calls having x < 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not changing the value of x in your `while` loop. As long as x is less than 10, it will loop forever. Consider using an `if` statement instead.

Answer (score 0):

the first 9 levels of your recursion depth are always less than 10

```
while x < 10
```

nothing is changing x to anything else

If you want to limit the recursion, re-structure to this:

```
while x < 10:
    x = x + 1
    test_recursion(x)
    test_recursion(x+1)
```